# Don't include polyfill to React JS with Slack Bolt

Tags: reactjs, slack, slack-api

I have a really simple ReactJS code that use the Slack Bolt package. When I run `npm run start` I have three errors :

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os'

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring'

The code

```
  const { WebClient } = require("@slack/web-api");
  const token = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN;
  const web = new WebClient(token);
  const r = web.channels.list()
  console.log(r);
```

I have many information on how to solve it but none worked.

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }

I tried to configure weback by adding this lines to a `webpack.config.js` on the project's root

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      assert: false,
      crypto: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      os: false,
      stream: false,
      path: false,
      querystring: false,
    },
  },
};
```

No solutions worked.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?